# Better way to fix imports after changing the package of imports

Tags: python, python-2.7

So I have two projects, A and B. A is framework project. B is an actual project where other developers extend the framework.
The project structure of Project A was:

```
    A
    |_apple
    |_ant
```

But now I have added test cases in it changed a little bit structure of the project. The project structure now is

```
    A
    |_src
    |  |_apple
    |  |_ant
    |_test
```

`apple` and `ant` are imported in project B in couple of hundred files. Now I have to update the import paths as previously the import statements were

```
    from apple import *
```

but now they should be

```
    from src.apple import *
```

My question is that is there any easier way to handle this change than manually updating the reference in each file?

Comment: Use the function of Find in Files in your IDE to find all lines (or simply find and replace)

Comment: I think what you did is awful. I'd would have done the following: `src -> A -> apple, ant` and `test` outside `src`. This would avoid changing all the imports in other places since `src` should *not* be visible in your package

Comment: One of the golden rules of writing a framework is that you do nothing that will break working code. You've broken that rule. Go back and unbreak it.

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow Yes that is what I am doing but I was asking that if there is more cool way to solve this problem

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I didn't get your idea. A is my project then how can I put source folder outside the project. I would be really grateful if you can explain a little bit more.

Comment: @BoarGules That is true. I would really appreciate if you can give me some pointers on what I should have done.

Comment: Seems to me that @GiacomoAlzetta has a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should only use `import src.apple` (or `from src.apple import ...`) if `src` really is a package. But in this case that doesn't seem to be true.

If it's just a directory holding your Python sources (e.g. modules and packages), than you could add the directory to your Python search path. For example, add the directory to the PYTHONPATH environment variable, or in your main Python file add `import sys; sys.path.append('src')`.